# is there a changelog server for ros.org package repositories?

Tags: ros, apt, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to be able to browse Ubuntu ROS package changelogs using the apt-get changelog command. For this a "changelog server" needs to be setup along the packge repositories. See apt-get(1) for detail.

Is such a server available for ros.org Ubuntu package repositories ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72811/is-there-a-changelog-server-for-ros.org-package-repositories-?/) by [mherrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/80/mherrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not.  We'd like to have one, however we have not found any standard tools to setup and create it. If you know of a toolchain to set one up please open a ticket on https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm with more information.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1